# Swift 3 Multi-Dimension Array, Worked in Swift 2.2 and previous

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, swift3, xcode8

I've been racking my brain for hours and feel like I've tried most things so I'm turning to the trusty Stack Overflow!

I have an array of arrays coming from a server that correlates to a unix timestamp and a value which looks like this:

`[[1475511843000,183649999],[1475512143000,183612691],[1475512443000,183503638]]`

I used to simply set this variable up as 
`var graphPoints:NSArray = []`

I'm now trying to convert to Swift3 and use `[[UInt32:Int]]()` to specify that I have an array containing other arrays which have a 32 Unsigned Integer as well as an Integer afterwards. No matter which way I've tried including standard vs. sugared syntax:

`[Int:[UInt32:Int]]()`

`[[UInt32:Int]]()`

`[[]]()`

allows me to access the second array due to a typing issue, normally giving an error akin to `Type 'Int?' has no subscript members`.

The data was in this format before I had a say as to how it would be formatted so I'm not able to adjust that, any help would be great appreciated.

The server call looks like this:
`Alamofire.request(urlString).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                let json = JSON(data);

```
            //print("GRAPH DATA POINTS JSON: \(json)")

            //some graphs don't contain data so we have to test for null
            if !json.isEmpty {
                self.graphPoints = json["data"].arrayObject! as! [(timestamp: UInt64, value: Int)]
                if self.graphPoints.count > 0 {
                    self.firstPriceInGraph = self.graphPoints[0][0].doubleValue
                    self.setupPercentageLabel()
                } else {
                    //no graph data available, hide something?
                    self.firstPriceInGraph = -1.0
                    if Helper.__DEBUG { print("NO DATA IN JSON... 1")}
                }
            } else {
                //no graph data available, hide something?
                self.firstPriceInGraph = -1.0
                if Helper.__DEBUG {print("NO DATA IN JSON... 2")}
            }

            self.graphView.reloadData()

        case .failure(let error):
            self.graphPoints = [(timestamp:UInt64, value:Int)]()
            self.graphView.reloadData()
            print("Get Graph Data - Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }`
```

[image: The Error]

`When trying Andrey Gordeev's answer`
[image: Initial Array Setup]

[image]

Comment: You have array of array and in first two declaration you are telling that it is Array of dictionary try once `[[UInt32]]`

Comment: @NiravD 1475511843000 doesn't suite `UInt32`. `UInt64` is a better choice here.

Comment: Results in Type 'UInt32' has no subscript members

Comment: @StuartP. What are you even trying to do here? Your numbers are too big to store in `UInt32`. Why are you storing arrays if they're always going to have 2 elements? Why are you using NSArray?

Comment: Looks like OP just wants to get the old Swift 2.2 code working just fine with Swift 3.0 :) Unfortunately, sometimes it's impossible.

Comment: Yeah, for now I just need it working so I can do a build! I of course want it to be as clean and maintainable as possible but clients don't care about code frequently.

Comment: Then just replace `NSArray` word with `[[UInt64]]` as I suggested. Quick-and-dirty solution

Comment: [[UInt64]]() does not work Andrey

Comment: @StuartP. it works just fine in my Playgrounds. Please update your question with relevant error message, code and screenshot.

Comment: @StuartP. that makes sense. See my updated answer.

Comment: Andrey I've added photos, that solution doesn't appear to work either, I'm assuming the issue lies more in JSON and I may end up having to comment a bunch of things out just to get it building and then knock out the issues one at a time.

Comment: @StuartP. can you try to switch back to `[[UInt64]]` and change `self.graphPoints[0][0].doubleValue` to `self.graphPoints[0][0]`? This should work

Comment: Actually, I don't think this helps. There is a problem with `graphPoints` and `firstPriceInGraph`: they have wrong types

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right, I've started changing the types and digging but I appreciate your help nevertheless!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
let array = [[UInt64]]()
```

or

```
let array: [[UInt64]] = [[1475511843000,183649999],[1475512143000,183612691],[1475512443000,183503638]]
```

What you're trying to define by `[Int:[UInt32:Int]]()` and `[[UInt32:Int]]()` is not an array of arrays. First one is a dictionary, where value is another dictionary. Second one is an array of dictionaries.

PS: As Alexander Momchilov mentioned, it's better to wrap your data to `[(UInt64, Int)]`

Comment: `Type 'UInt64' has no subscript members` is the result but I'll attempt to wrap the data, what's the best way to pull data out of this then as I imagine it won't be via [0][0] for example. Also I believe the data types need to be a part of that now so maybe `[(timestamp:UInt64, value:Int)]`

Comment: `Type 'UInt64' has no subscript members` is the result of what?

Comment: Of `let array = [[UInt64]]()` when I'm attempting to access it via `let value = self.graphPoints[0][0]`

Comment: @StuartP. What is the type of `self.graphPoints`? Did you replace `NSArray` with `[[UInt64]]`? `let value = array[0][0]` works just fine for me. Returns `1475511843000`

Answer (score 1):

> I'm now trying to convert to Swift 3 and use `[[UInt32:Int]]()` to specify that I have an array containing other arrays which have a 32 Unsigned Integer as well as an Integer afterwards.

That's not what at all what that means. `[[UInt32: Int]]()` is the shorthand for: `Array<Dictionary<UInt32, Int>>.init()`

The only way to have an array of 2 types, such as `UInt32` and `Int`, is to have the array store a super type of both of those types. In this case, `UInt32` and `Int` both share a conformance to `Integer` protocol, so you can store both `UInt32` and `Int` in an `Array<Integer>`. This is pretty gross though, as it'll require you to constantly explicitly down cast from `Integer` to `UInt32` or `Int`. The indirection that this introduces also has performance costs.

A better way of achieving a similar thing is to store tuples of UInt32 and Int:

```
let graphPoints: [(UInt32, Int)] = [
    (1475511843000, 183649999),
    (1475512143000, 183612691),
    (1475512443000, 183503638)
]
```

However, this doesn't even work, because `1475511843000` is too big to stope in a `UInt32`, whose max value is `4294967295` (`UInt32.max`).

Answer (score 1):

Just as you said, this is an `Array` of other `Array`s. `[[UInt32:Int]]()` would create an `Array` of `Dictionary`s instead because `[UInt32:Int]` is a `Dictionary` with `UInt32` as keys and `Int` as values.

Swift arrays only hold a single type of element, so you can do `[[Integer]]`, `Integer` being a protocol that both `UInt32` and `Int` conform to. Then when accessing you would have to explicitly cast to either `UInt32` or `Int` if you wanted them in those types.

You could also then convert that `[[Integer]]` to a `[(UInt32, Int)]`, an `Array` of tuples containing a `UInt32` and an `Int`.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is a *dictionary*, not a multi dimensional array.

```
[[UInt32:Int]]()
```

creates an array of dictionaries that has `UInt32` as keys and `Int` as values.

```
[Int:[UInt32:Int]]()
```

creates a dictionary that uses `Int` as keys and another dictionary type as values.

Both of the above is not what you want.

Since your data are `UInt32` - `Int` pairs, you probably shouldn't use a multidimensional array to store them because an array can only store one type of value.

My suggestion is to use an array of tuples:

```
[(UInt32, Int)]
```

Example usage:

```
theArray[3].0 // get the timestamp of the fourth item
theArray[7].1 // get the Int value of the eighth item
```

Alternatively, try a dictionary:

```
[UInt32: Int]
```

Note that this makes the data unordered. You can only access the values using the keys.

Comment: This seems to result in `Cannot subscript a value of type 'inout [(timestamp: UInt64, value: Int)]' (aka 'inout Array<(timestamp: UInt64, value: Int)>')` when attempting to access the data like so `let timestamp = self.graphPoints[0].timestamp`

Comment: @StuartP. I can't seem to reproduce this. Can you edit your question to show more code?